# Jquery add data to html before adding to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building html on the fly need to add data before I add it to DOM.  Since I am looping thru' lot of information,  I would like to add the relevant data info along with the dom I am building instead of adding the html and then looping thru again to add the data.

```
result.forEach(function(record) {
html += '<div id ="' record.ID + '">test content </div> ';

//add data to above
 });
```

I can do another loop here after adding it to DOM

```
$(body).append(html);
 testresult.forEach(function(record) {
   $("#" +record.ID).data(record);
 });
```

Comment: What you mean by `data`?

Comment: $(html).data(some object);

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes problem in the following line :

```
html += '<div id =record.testID' + '>test content </div> ';
________^______________________^___^_____________________^
```

You should fix that using double quotes because as it's now the string will be considered as `'<div id =record.testID'`.

```
html += '<div id="'+record.testID+'">test content </div>';
```

Or you could use separated definition :

```
$.each(result, function(index,record) {
  var div = $('<div>test content</div>'); 

  div.attr('id', record.testID);
  div.data('test', record.testDATA);

  $('body').append(div);
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var result = [{testID: 1,testDATA: 'data 1'},{testID: 2,testDATA: 'data 2'},{testID: 3,testDATA: 'data 3'}]
var html='';

$.each(result, function(index,record) {
  var div = $('<div>test content</div>'); 
  
  div.attr('id', record.testID);
  div.data('test', record.testDATA);
  
  console.log(div.data('test'));
  $('body').append(div);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are right but thats not the issue . 
I need to add $(div.record.testID).data(some object);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating strings to piece together your HTML, you may way to try something like this:

```
result.forEach(function(record) {
    $('.selector').append(function () {
        var $div = $('<div></div>');
        $div.attr('id', record.testID).text('some text');

        return $div;
    });
 });
```

This creates a new `div` jquery object for each item in result. You can use the `record` object to add attributes, data, text, etc to you object. It will be added the DOM when the callback passed into `.append` returns your new jquery DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

Start trying to use jQuery to create your html elements so you can take fully advantage of jQuery and its plugins.

Ex:

```
var div = $("<div></div>")         // create the element
    .text("test content")          // change the inner text
    .attr("id", record.testID);    // set the element id

div.appendTo("body");
```

You can check out [http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/] as a great source for learning jQuery.